# Sinister Shadow Games and Dimensional Fissure

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Can I activate 'Sinister Shadow Games' if Dimensional Fissure has already been activated and, if I can, do I get the second effect to flip up a face down Shaddoll?

**Sinister Shadow Games**

> Send 1 "Shaddoll" card from your Deck to the
>   Graveyard, then you can change any number of face-down Defense
>   Position "Shaddoll" monsters you control to face-up Defense Position.

**Dimensional Fissure**

> Any monster sent to the Graveyard is banished instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sinister Shadow Games can be activated even if the effect of Dimensional Fissure is active.  When Sinister Shadow Games resolves, the "Shaddoll" card will be banished instead of being sent to the Graveyard.

Because a "Shaddoll" card was not sent to the Graveyard, the second effect that flips a "Shaddoll" monster face-up will not resolve.

Problem-Solving Card Text can be applied to reach this conclusion. Effects which take the form "Do A, then do B" are such that A and B are sequential components. A resolves, then B resolves. For effects worded this way, if A does not resolve properly for any reason, B should not be resolved either. So if Sinister Shadow Games does not send a "Shaddoll" card from your Main Deck to the Graveyard (even if it banishes one instead), no "Shaddoll" monsters will be flipped face-up.